VBA 2 seemingly identical times in "HH:MM" format return different output
I have times in one column all "22:00" in "HH:MM" format. I run a function to get the shift pattern, which changes at 22:00.
"2" is late shift - up to 22:00
"3" is night shift - after 22:00.
I just wonder why the same times would give a different result.
This is the function. I know 3 and 2 have an "=" which means it could fit both criteria but if i put one as ">=" and the other as "<" off one of the time it doesn't change the output. I have calcswitched on.
Public Function GetShift(TimeIn As Date) As Long
  GetShift = Switch(TimeIn >= #10:00:00 PM#, 3, _
                TimeIn <= #6:00:00 AM#, 4, _
                TimeIn >= #6:00:00 AM# And TimeIn <= #2:00:00 PM#, 1, _
                TimeIn >= #2:00:00 PM# And TimeIn <= #10:00:00 PM#, 2 _
                )
End Function

This is the formula to run the function. I have no problem with this. It works perfectly
Sub gEtshiftformula()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  On Error Resume Next

   Dim r As Range, lr As Long
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set r = Range("E2:E" & lr).Cells
r.Formula = "=getshift(RC[2])"
End Sub




Please, add a simple formula in the column after the filtered one (let us say that the filtered column is B:B) =Value("B1") and fill it down. Excel keeps time as numeric values. Does the formula return the same for all rows? I cannot reproduce the behavior you explain. In my case (Office 2019) it shows only 3...

I think @FaneDuru is right, the value in the time column may be slightly less than 22:00:00. For example 21:59:59.86 is displayed as 22:00:00 but will be shown as shift 2. If you change the format of the time column to hh:mm:ss.00 then it will show different hours and minutes.

I've edited the comment to show what the suggestions produce as an image. There is a difference in one of the times when i put it as scientific formatting and extend the decimals. The hh:mm:ss.00 doesn't appear to show a difference. Value("B2") returns a #Value error message. The only way i can get them to be consistent is using the "Mround(b2,"00:01")" in column F, which returns column G. I'm a little bit stumped but i suppose the Mround formula is a workaround so i can settle for that. Thank you for your help. If you have any other ideas please suggest them as i am a little stumped still
